# Odoo 13 tax recompute on total

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-13

we have this situation after odoo migration from 10 to 13.

[image]

as you can see the taxes equal the total amount, when on the lines the tax is 0%.
I have tried with:

```
rec._compute_invoice_taxes_by_group()
rec._compute_amount()
rec._recompute_dynamic_lines(rec)
rec._onchange_tax_totals_json()
```

but nothing changes, the _compute_amount works for untaxed and total amount, but amount_by_group (Taxes field on the form) doesnt change.
Any suggestions? Which function we can trigger on the account.move so that taxes on total get updated?
Thanks a lot

Comment: How did you migrate?

Comment: openupgrade, but if you are enterprise odoo will do it for you

Comment: I'm wondering that there's nothing in openupgrade about it. Because this topic is nothing special but more a usual and expected thing in one of THE core apps.

Comment: Is the computation at all working? Try to just create a new invoice and play around with it.

Comment: yep computation is totally correct on new invoices, i tried to play with that field, yields as a typle,
#[('USt 19%', 19.0, 100.0, '19.00 €', '100.00 €', 2, 7), ('USt 7%', 52.5, 750.0, '52.50 €', '750.00 €', 2, 3)]
lis = list(self.amount_by_group[0])
_logger.info("LIST NOW %s" %lis)
lis[0] = "TEST"
lis[3] = '11.00 €'
self.amount_by_group = [tuple(lis)]
but doesnt update on the invoice form at all, and when printed in logger seems changed

Comment: Can you crosscheck if there is no tax_line_id on any of the `move.line`s (account.move.line_ids) on an example invoice?

Comment: there is 1 line on the invoice,
select * from account_move_line_account_tax_rel where account_move_line_id=119008;
 account_move_line_id | account_tax_id 
----------------------+----------------
               119008 |             55